# Cable can connect to laptop but not recognised on switch

Tags: network

I have a solid core all weather cat6 network cable running for 40m to an outbuilding which houses my work office. The cable is properly installed and screened. It is buried to the correct depth.

Recently it's been the case that the connection can be made directly on my laptop, but switches (and the wireless AP therein) don't recognise the cable being plugged in -- no lights, nothing recognised in software. Is this a cabling issue, and if so how come the laptop can connect but the switch can't? If it is a cabling issue, should I replace the cable or get an amplifier?

UPDATE:

On further investigation, there was found to be a break in one side of the orange pairs near the RJ45 connector. Re-tipping the cable fixed this. However I still would love to know why we had the behaviour, which to my mind does not make sense. So if anyone can explain it that would be brilliant.

Comment: Make sure that type of your cable cross over or straight.

Comment: @infra on modern network equipment, the mdix is automatically detected and set accordingly to support the connected medium.

Comment: @user56700 agreed, but what we knows is ,it is a 40m cable. Thats all

Comment: My guess would be, that your cable is defective. You need to hire a proper cable technician/electrician, who can test it and thereby find out if there is a problem with the physical cable.

Comment: Have you tried putting the cable into other ports? Maybe the port isn't working properly.

Comment: Ports are fine, but a good question

Comment: There is no amplifier for such things. Did you run the cable yourself, or did your company hire a professional (outside cabling is a specialty that has legal and financial implications, and it is best left to professionals)? If your company depends on its cabling, it should really hire professional installers, especially with Category-6 and above cabling.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible reasons the link doesn't come up:

1. You're trying to link two MDI (client side) or two MDI-X (switch side) ports with each other that do not support Auto MDI-X - auto mode is extremely common today but there are still some rigid ports around. Check which ports types you're connecting and try using a crossover adapter.
2. The link comes up between Fast Ethernet (FE) nodes (100 Mbit/s) but fails between Gigabit Ethernet (GE) nodes. GE requires all four pairs to work while FE just uses two pairs. Some GE nodes fall back to FE when pairs are missing but many don't - the link just doesn't come up. Check the cable for complete pairs and proper function - at least for continuity and shorts. If all fails you should hire a professional service to test the cable (or redeploy if possible).

Regarding "40 m" cable - per standard, *stranded/flexible* cable must not exceed 10 m (5 m on each side) while *solid*/rigid cable must not exceed 90 m, 100 m in total. If you've got 40 m of flexible cable deployed you might need to redeploy. Of course, it's also possible the cable is damaged (thx @Ron). Depending on the run and the weather conditions, I'd consider using fiber for outdoor/underground.